# How to filter out virtual SIM card users during phone number verification?

Tags: security, sms

These days it seems like a lot of services are requiring you to use a text message to verify your account's existence in some way. However, I want to be sure that a user isn't using "free text message" numbers found in a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=YIs&ei=5UwbW4C6GrLy5gLQsIfwBQ&q=free%20text%20number%20online&oq=free%20text%20number%20online&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i5i30k1j0i8i30k1l7.12179.20361.0.20513.23.21.0.1.1.0.149.2094.12j9.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.18.1606...35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i20i264k1j0i20i263i264k1j0i131i67k1j0i13k1j0i7i30k1.0.z4jnz7joDwo) as well as any numbers associated with Google voice.

Are there any cell phone number lookups that I can use to ensure that a SIM card is not virtually generated?  I know Google has knowledge of these fake number services, which is why I ask.

Comment: I think there are virtual and physical sims, and that you may be able to tell apart somehow. However, some of these services operate with real physical sims, and they also have paid subscriptions that people really use. You would probably not want to filter those, but they are the same as "fake" numbers. So in short, what you want is not really possible.

Comment: Thanks to your knowledge, I have changed the question title to: "How to filter out virtual SIM card users during phone number verification?"  ... Of course nothing is ever 100% secure, but it would be nice to come as close as possible

Comment: Well, yes, but if I can buy a physical sim number for 5$ for a week, what's the point in filtering virtual sims? I can achieve what I want anyway. :)

Comment: I know, but my point is to make you do that :)